# JQM registering same even multiple times on same object

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery

I'm building a test mobile app using a multi-page template but JQM is incrementally registering the same event on the same object each time I'm navigating from the main page to the search page.

If I'm on the main page and navigate to the search page, the first time 1 onclick event attached to my "li a"'s within the UL but if I go back to the main page again using the standard JQM back button and click search page again there are 2 events exactly the same registered on the each "li a" with in the UL. If I do it a third time there are 3, and so on...

Relevant Search Page Markup:

```
<div id="searchResults">
    <ul id="catResult" class="ui-listview" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="c" data-dividertheme="b">
        <li data-role="listdivider" data-theme="b">Search Categories</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

JQM Code for search page:

```
$('body').on('pagebeforeshow', '#searchPage', function(event){ // check if page is shown then execute code
    setScrollBar("show");
    buildCategoryList();
    setListMenuHeight(".ui-2col-layout .ui-2column-grid .ui-block-a", wHeight);

   // This event register is being registered multiple times
   $('#catList').on('click', 'li a', function(){
       var href = $(this).attr('href');
       var id = href.split('=');
       console.log('spLoadCategoryResults('+id[1]+')');
       spLoadCategoryResults(id[1]); // return results from database
    });    

    $("[data-rel=back]").click(function(){
                    // removes appended elements from the DOM is they exist
        cleanPage(['#catResult li','#locationMap #mapCanvas','#searchResults #spResult']); 
    });

    // DEBUG - shows how many times the event is registered
    var data = jQuery._data( catList, "events" );
    console.log(data);      

});
```

Debug results:

> click
>           [Object { type="click", origType="click", guid=306, more...}, Object { type="click", origType="click", guid=469, more...}, Object { type="click", origType="click", guid=537, more...}]

```
0
    Object { type="click", origType="click", guid=306, more...}

1
    Object { type="click", origType="click", guid=469, more...}

2
    Object { type="click", origType="click", guid=537, more...}

delegateCount
    3

remove
    [Object { type="remove", origType="remove", guid=210, more...}]
```

Each of these are registered on the "li a".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with this code.  You are attaching another click event to the anchor items every time you navigate to the search page.

Here is jsfiddle to demonstrate  http://jsfiddle.net/d2Jzb/

```
// This event register is being registered multiple times
 $('#catList').on('click', 'li a', function(){
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   var id = href.split('=');
   console.log('spLoadCategoryResults('+id[1]+')');
   spLoadCategoryResults(id[1]); // return results from database
});
```

That click event appears to be independent from anything happening in the pagebeforeshow event.  Just take the event declaration out of the pagebeforeshow event declaration.

Comment: thank you... i was working under the assumption that all event registers for the page needed to be included in that pages init...

I moved the event register outside into the main body of my script file and it all works fine now... Thank you